# Display an image 2nd edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opencv

I have a problem with my c++ opencv program. It should show a picture I loaded in, but after debugging only a grey window pops up. Here is my code:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h> 
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "IMG_7321_.jpg" );
    cvNamedWindow( "IMG_7321_", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("IMG_7321_", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "IMG_7321_" );

    return 0;
}
```

The .jpg file is in the project folder.

Can anybody tell me what I have to do to get the picture to be shown. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the "release" line shouldn't be `cvReleaseImage( img );`?

Comment: @KerrekSB The cvReleaseImage call is correct. It modifies the `img` variable so it's passed by reference.

Comment: @SSteve: If `img` is to be passed by reference, why does the OP pass it as a pointer?

Comment: @KerrekSB: The function takes a pointer to a pointer. Here's the definition: `void cvReleaseImage(IplImage** image)`. [Here's the documentation.](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#releaseimage) I meant the pointer is passed by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check to see if you are successfully loading the file. Try this:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "IMG_7321_.jpg" );
    if (!img) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Image not found\n");
        return -1;
    }
    cvNamedWindow( "IMG_7321_", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage("IMG_7321_", img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "IMG_7321_" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To SSteve: i cant check because the command window only opens for a few milliseconds and then closes instantly -> i cant read the output^^

Comment: To SSteve: i managed to check now, without the "return -1;" the command window stayed open^^ (u know why?). How can i make the program load the file? (im so sorry for all those questions, but this stuff is just so complicated and nothing like this is listed in the documentary)

Comment: after debug i get the following:                                                          
The program '[164] 3-2).exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: If the program closes instantly, that means it's not successfully loading the image and is hitting the `return -1` line. Make sure the file name is correct and that it's in the same folder as your exe. The folder with your exe may not be the same as the folder containing your source files. I'm on OS X so I don't know where Visual Studio puts its files.

Comment: hi SSteve, now it works! :D thank you very much! I put the file in the same folder as the .exe... Its so good to know where u have to put the files! i had it in the project folder but not in the same folder as the .exe.... Again thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. And welcome to Stack Overflow. If you find an answer helpful, you should accept it. You can [read about accepting answers here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).